# Flink EMR Program failing

Tags: apache-flink, emr, flink-streaming

I have, what I would consider, a fairly simple Flink program.  Sourced from a Kafka stream, filter's applied, process function applied, flat map applied, and sent to a Redis sink.  Running this locally in a stand alone environment on my dev box, there is no problem.  I am trying to push this into production on AWS EMR, I followed the guide for running a Flink program on EMR.  After my first test, I had a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error, so I made adjustments to reduce the amount of data stored.  My next try the program ran for much longer, but eventually failed, not giving any indication of a type of error like it had previously.

I am unsure how to go about debugging problems that I suspect may be a side effect of running on EMR.  Most of the monitoring metrics in the EMR console are useless as far as I can tell.  If it matters, I am running the program as a Step in EMR, the guide i followed is here `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-flink.html`.  This program is also suppose to be an always up solution, basically it will constantly be reading from the Kafka Stream and processing the data(If that matters at all, not sure if there is a different configuration I should be using for an always up solution)

I'll be happy to provide any information needed to help me getting this into production.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that the log files are empty, or are you unable to access them? FWIW, in general I recommend running your own Flink installation on EMR, rather than one from AWS, and in this case, Flink 1.3.2 is more stable than 1.3.1, so it's probably worth a try. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/aws.html#custom-emr-installation

Comment: The log files are not empty(They have the startup output), but they do not contain any sort of stack trace or error that i normally see if there is a problem with the cluster.  I will try another test using 1.3.2.  Are there any good ways to monitor resource usage while a job is running?  Are there any settings I should be setting if I plan on having my job running 24/7?

Comment: You can look at the system metrics: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#system-metrics

Comment: YARN is rather hard-nosed about enforcing memory limits; perhaps your application is being nuked for consuming too much memory. I suggest adjusting taskmanager.memory.fraction (especially if you are using RocksDB, which consumes off-heap memory): https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/config.html#managed-memory

Comment: Are you holding onto state indefinitely? You may need to add a timer and clear state that is no longer needed.

Comment: I do have a state in my process function that I don't believe I am clearing. 
 Any information on how to clear state?  It seemed like a logical step in my thinking(once my data is calculated and is written to my Sink, I am done with it), but I never saw anything on removing states, I assumed it would be handled automatically when Scala didn't see the state being referenced anymore.  As of right now I turned off check pointing to try and get the program stable, then I was going to attempt to move everything to a RocksDB(previously I had used an FsStateBackend) once stability was solved.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now state has a clear function. going to see if that lowers my memory footprint.

Comment: Can you try to increase `taskmanager.heap.mb` something like `[
    {
      "Classification": "flink-conf",
      "Properties": {
        "taskmanager.heap.mb":"4000",
        "taskmanager.memory.fraction": "0.9"
      }
    }
]` when you create your EMR cluster